# DynamoDB write spikes alternative

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following situation:

1. Item is added to DynamoDB table (*triggers Lambda function*)
2. Lambda function checks who has subscribed to this particular item
3. Lambda function saves "user notifications" to another DynamoDB table

Example:

- User subscribes to (1)**white** (2)**small** (3)**cat**  (*three attributes*)
- Item is added to DynamoDB table and it happens to be **white small cat**
- Notification is saved in order to show it to user if he/she logs in

---

DynamoDB is great but I see a potential problem: if there are thousands of subscribers to same item, Lambda function has to write thousands of "notifications" to table. DynamoDB is not great for spikes.

My normal write throughput without this is only 10-20, 
1000 write throughput costs over $500. These write spikes would choke DynamoDB instantly or either cost me thousands of wasted dollars.

### ---

How to solve this issue? I can't think of any suitable AWS service or reasonable DynamoDB hack.

Comment: DynamoDB will allow you to burst for short periods of time.  When capacity is not fully utilized it accumulates and you can use up to 5 minutes worth of capacity at max burst rate of 1000 writes per second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decouple the writer from DynamoDB.

Instead of writing directly to DynamoDB, you could push 'write requests' onto SQS and then have a consumer process remove items from SQS at a sensible rate and write them to DynamoDB. Doing this would allow you to maximize your use of DynamoDB provisioned throughput, regardless of what that provisioned level was.

Here's a TV show voting example ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2gfP_rtAhw), [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/arc313-so-you-think-you-can-architect-aws-reinvent-2014)).